# Spacemacs keybinding not behaving as expected

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

The following keybindings work when simply moving. However, when pressing `d` and then one of these keys, the behavior is not as expected.

When pressing `dL` it will delete until the end of the page. When pressing `dH` it will delete until the top of the page.

I suspect that there are some default bindings for these keys that are not overwritten. Is there a delete state map that I need to define this for as well or something I need to specify to overwrite the keys?

```lisp
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "H") (kbd "^")) ; H goes to beginning of the line
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "L") (kbd "$")) ; L goes to end of the line
```

Comment: *"the behavior is not as expected"* means what? You don't say what you expect. Please be specific about what you expect vs what you see instead.

Comment: I agree. It is fixed now

Comment: Thanks ---------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` and `$` is bind to `evil-motion-state-map` through `evil-define-motion`, so you need:

```lisp
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "H") 'evil-first-non-blank)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "L") 'evil-end-of-line)
```